# I'm unable to get my API token using the below POST code

Tags: post, authorization, token

I am trying to get a authentication token using this code below, i am kind of confused on how to go about it.

```
   url = "https://api.tradingcentral.com/authentication/v3"

headers = {"accept: application/json",
           "Content-Type: application/json"}

data = {"clientId": "rc-xxx", "password": "4xxxxxxxxxx", "endUserId": "testuserid", "admin": 'false'}

response = requests.post(url = url, headers=headers, params=data) 

df = response.text
```

I seem to be doing something wrong.

Comment: try to use -d @data.json.this will be easier for post json data

Comment: Please can you give better context on how to use it, where do i include the -d @data.json.